# How can I create a loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

I have this function:

```
def get_topName(dataset, start_year, end_year, sex):
    subset = dataset[(dataset.year >= start_year) & (dataset.year <= end_year) & (dataset.sex == sex)]
    subset1 = subset.drop(columns=['year', 'prop', 'per1000'])
    subset2 = subset1.groupby("name", as_index=False).n.sum()
    subset3 = subset2.sort_values("n" , ascending = False)
    return subset3[0:1]
```

I am using this function to find the top baby names in each decade. I want to create a loop that will find the top names (male and female) for each decade starting in 1950. I tried to make a for loop, but I am having trouble getting it to work with multiple variables.

I want something simple, like this:

```
for x in decadeList:
        names = get_topName(baby_df, start_year, end_year, sex)
return names
```

And maybe my decadeList would be able to have a start year, end year, and sex? Is this possible? I'm trying to keep this very simple/beginner methods.

Comment: In your loop, you need the `x` in `for x in decadeList` to carry all of the information to put into your function. If `x` contains all of `dataset, start_year, end_year, sex` then you can unpack it with `names = get_topName(*x)` otherwise you need to pass all of the arguments in some fashion

Comment: Also, in your function return, you can simplify a bit: `subset3[0:1]` is the same as just saying `subset3[0]`

Comment: Alright, but I got an error message. "'return' outside function"

Comment: Returns are for functions, your loop isn't a function. You would need to declare an empty list (or other data structure) and `append` to it in your loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a dataframe with 3 columns: `decade, f_name, m_name`. You just need to loop over `decadeList`, get the top names for both sexs and include the new record to the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

def get_topName(dataset, start_year, end_year, sex):
    subset = dataset[(dataset.year >= start_year) & (dataset.year <= end_year) & (dataset.sex == sex)]
    subset1 = subset.drop(columns=['year', 'prop', 'per1000'])
    subset2 = subset1.groupby("name", as_index=False).n.sum()
    subset3 = subset2.sort_values("n" , ascending = False)
    return subset3[0]

columns = ['decade', 'f_name', 'm_name']
top_names_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
for decade in decadeList:
  f_name = get_topName(baby_df, decade, decade+10, female_sex)
  m_name = get_topName(baby_df, decade, decade+10, male_sex)
  top_names_df.loc[len(top_names_df)] = [deacade, f_name, m_name]
```

Comment: How would I see this top_names_df?

Comment: Just use `print(top_names_df)`

Comment: Alright, that seems to work, but its only printing one name and value when I have 5 decades to check. How can I get it to show me all the names?

Comment: is your list of `decadeList` actually containing the 5 decades...?

Comment: Yes, its listed like 'decadeList = [[baby_df, 1950, 1960, "M"],...' and then I used the *x in f_name and m_name

Comment: just make a list like `[1950, 1960,...] ` and change female_sex with 'F' and male_sex with 'M'